# BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference when using linux linked list

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to write the assignment in Operating System Concept 9th, chapter 2, which is writing a simple linux module. I write the code following the example in the book, but got a null pointer dereference error while deleting items in the linked list.
Here is my code.

````
  1 #include <linux/module.h>
  2 #include <linux/kernel.h>
  3 #include <linux/list.h>
  4 #include <linux/slab.h>
  5 /* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
  6 
  7 struct birthday{
  8     int day;
  9     int month;
 10     int year;
 11     struct list_head list;
 12 };
 13 
 14 struct list_head birthday_list;
 15 
 16 int simple_init(void)
 17 {
 18        printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");
 19        LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);
 20        struct birthday *person;
 21        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
 22        person->day=24;
 23        person->month=1;
 24        person->year=2000;
 25        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
 26        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list); 
 27        struct birthday *ptr;
 28        list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list){
 29            printk(KERN_INFO "Birthday: %d/%d/%d\n", ptr->year, ptr->month, ptr->day);
 30        }
 31        return 0;
 32 }
 33 
 34 /* This function is called when the module is removed. */
 35 void simple_exit(void) {
 36         printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
 37         struct birthday *ptr, *next;
 38 
 39         list_for_each_entry_safe(ptr, next, &birthday_list, list){
 40             printk(KERN_INFO "Birthday: %d/%d/%d\n", ptr->year, ptr->month, ptr->day);
 41             list_del(&(ptr->list));
 42             kfree(ptr);
 43         }
 44 
 45         printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Successfully\n");
 46 }
 47 module_init( simple_init );
 48 module_exit( simple_exit );
 49 
 50 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
 51 MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
 52 MODULE_AUTHOR("SGG");```
````

Answer (score 2):

### Initialize global variable `birthday_list`

The global variable `birthday_list` has implicit initialization `{NULL, NULL}` which is not a valid empty list. **That is the cause of the null pointer dereference in `simple_exit()`.** A valid empty list has the head node's `next` and `prev` members pointing to the head node itself.

You can define and initialize the global `birthday_list` variable using the `LIST_HEAD` macro:

```
LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);
```

However, it is preferable to declare it `static`:

```
static LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);
```

### Remove `LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);` from `simple_init()`

In `simple_init()`, `LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);` is creating a local variable `birthday_list`, but you should be using the global variable of the same name. So just remove `LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);` from `simple_init()`.